# XElement add node on specific position not working as expected

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xelement

I've got the following XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<JMF SenderID="InkZone-Controller" Version="1.2">
  <Command ID="cmd.00695" Type="Resource">
    <ResourceCmdParams ResourceName="InkZoneProfile" JobID="K_41">
      <InkZoneProfile ID="r0013" Class="Parameter" Locked="False" Status="Available" PartIDKeys="SignatureName SheetName Side Separation" DescriptiveName="Schieberwerte von DI" ZoneWidth="32">
        <InkZoneProfile SignatureName="SIG1">
          <InkZoneProfile Locked="false" SheetName="S1">
            <InkZoneProfile Side="Front">
              <ColorPool Class="Parameter" DescriptiveName="Colors for the job" Status="Available" />
              <Color Name="PANTONE 647 C" CMYK="1 1 0 0" sRGB="0 0 1" />
              <Color Name="Black" CMYK="1 1 0 0" sRGB="0 0 1" />
              <Color Name="Yellow" CMYK="1 1 0 0" sRGB="0 0 1" />
              <Color Name="Magenta" CMYK="1 1 0 0" sRGB="0 0 1" />
              <Color Name="Cyan" CMYK="1 1 0 0" sRGB="0 0 1" />
            </InkZoneProfile>
            <InkZoneProfile Separation="Cyan" ZoneSettingsX="0  0,006 0" />
            <InkZoneProfile Separation="Magenta" ZoneSettingsX="0 0,031  0" />
            <InkZoneProfile Separation="Yellow" ZoneSettingsX="0 0,021  0" />
            <InkZoneProfile Separation="Black" ZoneSettingsX="0 0,005  0" />
            <InkZoneProfile Separation="PANTONE 647 C" ZoneSettingsX="0,002 0"/>
          </InkZoneProfile>
        </InkZoneProfile>
      </InkZoneProfile>
    </ResourceCmdParams>
  </Command>
</JMF>
```

I want to add a node specifically after `<InkZoneProfile Side="Front">`. I issue the following expression for that:

```
XElement InkZonePath = XmlDoc.Root.Descendants("InkZoneProfile").Where(z => (string)z.Attribute("Side") == "Front").SingleOrDefault();
var InkZoneProfilePosition = InkZonePath.Parent; 
if (InkZoneProfilePosition != null)
                    {
                        InkZoneProfilePosition.Add(new XElement("InkZoneProfile",
                                    new XAttribute("Separation", x.colorname),
                                    new XAttribute("ZoneSettingsX", x.colorvalues)));
                    }
```

Instead of adding the node in the position i specified , the node is added just after `<ColorPool Class>` node  - i need it to be just after `<InkZoneProfile Side="Front">`

Example of the outputh i'm looking for:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<JMF SenderID="InkZone-Controller" Version="1.2">
  <Command ID="cmd.00695" Type="Resource">
    <ResourceCmdParams ResourceName="InkZoneProfile" JobID="K_41">
      <InkZoneProfile ID="r0013" Class="Parameter" Locked="False" Status="Available" PartIDKeys="SignatureName SheetName Side Separation" DescriptiveName="Schieberwerte von DI" ZoneWidth="32">
        <InkZoneProfile SignatureName="SIG1">
          <InkZoneProfile Locked="false" SheetName="S1">
            <InkZoneProfile Side="Front">
                       <InkZoneProfile Separation="Cyan" ZoneSettingsX="0 0,005 " />
            <InkZoneProfile Separation="Magenta" ZoneSettingsX="0  0" />
            <InkZoneProfile Separation="Yellow" ZoneSettingsX="0 0,021 0" />
            <InkZoneProfile Separation="Black" ZoneSettingsX="0 0,005 " />
            <InkZoneProfile Separation="PANTONE 647 C" ZoneSettingsX="0 0,003 " />
              <ColorPool Class="Parameter" DescriptiveName="Colors for the job" Status="Available" />
              <Color Name="PANTONE 647 C" CMYK="1 1 0 0" sRGB="0 0 1" />
              <Color Name="Black" CMYK="1 1 0 0" sRGB="0 0 1" />
              <Color Name="Yellow" CMYK="1 1 0 0" sRGB="0 0 1" />
              <Color Name="Magenta" CMYK="1 1 0 0" sRGB="0 0 1" />
              <Color Name="Cyan" CMYK="1 1 0 0" sRGB="0 0 1" />
            </InkZoneProfile>
          </InkZoneProfile>
        </InkZoneProfile>
      </InkZoneProfile>
    </ResourceCmdParams>
  </Command>
</JMF>
```

When I debug the code, the variable, even after the suggested changes, the var still contains the `<ColorPool>` node.

Is there an way to do that? All examples I saw around the web and the help I got from here mentioned to use Descendants(CORRECTED: using parent now) since I want to add the node after some root level's descendants.

Thanks in advance.

### EDIT1: Code change updated based on Sakura's comment - Resultant XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<JMF SenderID="InkZone-Controller" Version="1.2">
  <Command ID="cmd.00695" Type="Resource">
    <ResourceCmdParams ResourceName="InkZoneProfile" JobID="K_41">
      <InkZoneProfile ID="r0013" Class="Parameter" Locked="False" Status="Available" PartIDKeys="SignatureName SheetName Side Separation" DescriptiveName="Schieberwerte von DI" ZoneWidth="32">
        <InkZoneProfile SignatureName="SIG1">
          <InkZoneProfile Locked="false" SheetName="S1">
            <InkZoneProfile Side="Front">
              <ColorPool Class="Parameter" DescriptiveName="Colors for the job" Status="Available" />
              <Color Name="PANTONE 647 C" CMYK="1 1 0 0" sRGB="0 0 255" />
              <Color Name="Black" CMYK="1 1 0 0" sRGB="0 0 255" />
              <Color Name="Yellow" CMYK="1 1 0 0" sRGB="0 0 255" />
              <Color Name="Magenta" CMYK="1 1 0 0" sRGB="0 0 255" />
              <Color Name="Cyan" CMYK="1 1 0 0" sRGB="0 0 255" />
              <InkZoneProfile Separation="Name" ZoneSettingsX="Value" />
              <InkZoneProfile Separation="Name" ZoneSettingsX="Value" />
              <InkZoneProfile Separation="Name" ZoneSettingsX="Value" />
              <InkZoneProfile Separation="Name" ZoneSettingsX="Value" />
              <InkZoneProfile Separation="Name" ZoneSettingsX="Value" />
            </InkZoneProfile>
          </InkZoneProfile>
        </InkZoneProfile>
      </InkZoneProfile>
    </ResourceCmdParams>
  </Command>
</JMF>
```

Comment: Can you post an example XML you expect?

Comment: Check the update i made to the question.

Comment: Still don't clear. So you want `<level6><level7/><newlevel/></level6>` instead of `<level6><level7><newlevel/></level7></level6>`?

Comment: It will be more clear if you can post two XML: one is what you having, one is what you want to have.

Comment: Check my edit please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove this line:

```
var InkZoneProfilePosition = InkZonePath.Parent;
```

Then change `Add` to `AddFirst`. It should be:

```
    XElement InkZonePath = XmlDoc.Root.Descendants("InkZoneProfile").Where(z => (string)z.Attribute("Side") == "Front").SingleOrDefault();
    //var InkZoneProfilePosition = InkZonePath.Parent;
    if (InkZonePath != null)
    {
        InkZonePath.AddFirst(new XElement("InkZoneProfile",
                    new XAttribute("Separation", "Name"),
                    new XAttribute("ZoneSettingsX", "Value")));
    }
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was doing before and the result is the node being added in the wrong position (just like the sample file i posted).

Comment: You want to add an element `InkZoneProfile` as a child of `<InkZoneProfile Side="Front">`, right?

Comment: Exactly that. That's the deal. He's adding always like a child of ColorPool , instead of adding like a child of InkZoneProfile.

Comment: Can you copy/paste exactly what I typed to your code and see if it does what you need?

Comment: Check my edit please. I added the output generated from your code.

Comment: @PabloCosta I see that `<InkZoneProfile Separation="Name" ZoneSettingsX="Value" />`   is a child of `<InkZoneProfile Side="Front">`. So this is not what you want?

Comment: This is exactly what i want ; add <InkZoneProfile Separation="Name" ZoneSettingsX="Value" /> just after <InkZoneProfile Side="Front"> ; exactly after , on that position - otherwise the software who's going to read this file won't recognize the data.

Comment: Ok. Change form `Add` to `AddFirst`.

Comment: YAY ! You're a genius. Thanks. You're always helping me :) ! If there's anything i can do for helping you send a message. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @PabloCosta Ok. One problem is, if you have 3 element: e1, e1, e3, it will insert e3 first, then e2, e1. To solve this, you should add e3 first, then e2, e1

Comment: Got it. But this isn't a problem at all. In the file i'm reading, item e1 corresponds to ef1 in the file, e2 to ef2 ...that way it doesn't matter the order they appear - they'll correspond to the correct color. They just need to be in the place i need :)

Answer (score 1):

Problem is your query returns `Descendants` of a given name( *not* that element itself). You can get the parent of that element by reading `.Parent`.

```
var firstdescendant = XmlDoc.Root.Descendants("level6")
  .Where(z => (string)z.Attribute("leveltype") == "thislevel").SingleOrDefault();


var level6element = firstdescendant.Parent; // add null check to  firstdescendant (if required)
```

Working [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WKWfDo)

Comment: There's no option for adding .Parent here - says i'm missing some reference.

Comment: My bad, I did not copy whole of your query. Updated now.

Comment: Thanks. Check my edit please perhaps i added the whole info about my issue.